# Create an array based on two objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have two objects, that contains same number of properties:

```
object1: {
    prop1: 'data12',
    prop2: 'data13',
    prop3: 'data58',
    prop4: 'xyz',
    // more props here... 
  }

object2: {
    prop1: 123,
    prop2: 'email@gmail.com',
    prop3: 'text',
    prop4: 'bla',
    // more props here... 
  }
```

I want to build an array `{name: '', value: ''}` based on this objects:

```
[
  { data12: 123 },
  { data13: 'email@gmail.com' },
  { data58: text },
  { xyz: 'bla' },
]
```

How can you do that? The number of properties could be different.

Comment: Is the properties appear in both object?

Comment: @lucumt yes, correct

Comment: So you can just my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using `Object.keys()` can do it

```js
let object1 = {
    prop1: 'data12',
    prop2: 'data13',
    prop3: 'data58',
    prop4: 'xyz',
  }

let object2 = {
    prop1: '123',
    prop2: 'email@gmail.com',
    prop3: 'text',
    prop4: 'bla',
  }
  
let result =[]
let obj = {}
Object.keys(object1).forEach(k =>{
  obj[object1[k]] = object2[k]
})
result.push(obj)

// combined with reduce can also do it
/*
let obj =Object.keys(object1).reduce((a,c) => {
  a[object1[c]] = object2[c]
  return a
},{})
*/ 

result.push(obj)


console.log(result)
```

Comment: what would be the best way to validate if the pops on obj1 and obj2 mismatch?

Comment: @sreginogemoh in my option,we need to iterate the properties and check if it appear on another object,maybe others have better solution